# Delete a few months from the calendar on shiny

Tags: r, shiny

The shiny code below generates graphs for the days shown in `date2`, which in this case are the days 30/04, 17/05, 30/06 and 01/07.

I would like on shiny to only display graphs that are later than my `date1`(28/06). My calendar has the option of April and May, but I don't want these months to be shown, as I don't want to generate graphs for 30/04 and 17/05.

Executable code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

function.test<-function(){

  df1 <- structure(
    list(date1= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
         date2 = c("2021-04-30","2021-05-17","2021-06-30","2021-06-30","2021-07-01","2021-07-01"),
         Category = c("FDE","ABC","FDE","ABC","FDE","ABC"),
         Week= c("Friday","Monday","Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Friday"),
         DR1 = c(4,1,6,3,1,3),
         DR01 = c(4,1,4,3,1,3), DR02= c(4,2,6,2,2,4),DR03= c(9,5,4,7,5,2),
         DR04 = c(5,4,3,2,3,4),DR05 = c(5,4,5,4,2,4),
         DR06 = c(2,4,3,2,2,4),DR07 = c(2,5,4,4,4,2),
         DR08 = c(3,4,5,4,2,4),DR09 = c(2,3,4,4,4,2)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
  
  
  return(df1)
}

f1 <- function(df1, dmda, CategoryChosse) {
  
  x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DR0"))
  
  x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
  PV<-select(x, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))
  
  med<-PV %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median))
  
  SPV<-df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Category', 'Week')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())
  
  SPV<-data.frame(SPV)
  
  mat1 <- df1 %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(starts_with("DR0")) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
    mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
    filter(cs == 0) %>%
    pull(name)
  
  (dropnames <- paste0(mat1,"_",mat1, "_PV"))
  
  SPV <- SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(-any_of(dropnames))
  
  datas<-SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
    group_by(Category) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR0"), sum)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols= -Category, names_pattern = "DR0(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = readr::parse_number(name))
  colnames(datas)[-1]<-c("Days","Numbers")
  
  if(as.Date(dmda) < min(as.Date(df1$date1))){
    datas <- datas %>% 
      group_by(Category) %>% 
      slice(1:max(Days)+1) %>%
      ungroup
  }else{
    datas <- datas %>% 
      group_by(Category) %>% 
      slice((as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
        df1$Category == first(Category)])):max(Days)+1) %>%
      ungroup
  }
  
  plot(Numbers ~ Days,  xlim= c(0,45), ylim= c(0,30),
       xaxs='i',data = datas,main = paste0(dmda, "-", CategoryChosse))
  
  model <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = datas, algorithm = "port")
  
  new.data <- data.frame(Days = with(datas, seq(min(Days),max(Days),len = 45)))
  new.data <- rbind(0, new.data)
  lines(new.data$Days,predict(model,newdata = new.data),lwd=2)
  coef<-coef(model)[2]
  points(0, coef, col="red",pch=19,cex = 2,xpd=TRUE)
  text(.99,coef + 1,max(0, round(coef,1)), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")
  
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       
                                       uiOutput("date"),
                                       uiOutput("mycode"),
                                       br(),
                                       
                                       
                                     ),
                                     
                                     mainPanel(
                                       tabsetPanel(
                                         tabPanel("", plotOutput("graph",width = "100%", height = "600")
                                         )
                                       ),
                                     ))
                          )))


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(function.test())
  
  output$date <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
    disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date2)), origin = "1970-01-01")
    dateInput(input = "date2", 
              label = h4("Data"),
              min = min(data()$date2),
              max = max(data()$date2),
              value = min(data()$date2),
              format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
              datesdisabled = disabled)
    
  })
  
  output$mycode <- renderUI({
    req(input$date2)
    df1 <- data()
    df2 <- df1[as.Date(df1$date2) %in% input$date2,]
    selectInput("code", label = h4("Code"),choices=unique(df2$Category))
  })
  
  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    req(input$date2,input$code)
    f1(data(),as.character(input$date2),as.character(input$code))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `dateInput`, if we take the `subset`, it should work

```
data <- reactive(function.test())
  
  output$date <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    subdf1 <- subset(data(), as.Date(date2) > as.Date(date1))
    all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
    disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date2)), origin = "1970-01-01")
    dateInput(input = "date2", 
              label = h4("Data"),
              min = min(subdf1$date2),
              max = max(subdf1$date2),
              value = min(subdf1$date2),
              format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
              datesdisabled = disabled)
    
  })
```

-checking the output

[image]

[image]

---

-full code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
#library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

function.test<-function(){
  
  df1 <- structure(
    list(date1= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
         date2 = c("2021-04-30","2021-05-17","2021-06-30","2021-06-30","2021-07-01","2021-07-01"),
         Category = c("FDE","ABC","FDE","ABC","FDE","ABC"),
         Week= c("Friday","Monday","Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Friday"),
         DR1 = c(4,1,6,3,1,3),
         DR01 = c(4,1,4,3,1,3), DR02= c(4,2,6,2,2,4),DR03= c(9,5,4,7,5,2),
         DR04 = c(5,4,3,2,3,4),DR05 = c(5,4,5,4,2,4),
         DR06 = c(2,4,3,2,2,4),DR07 = c(2,5,4,4,4,2),
         DR08 = c(3,4,5,4,2,4),DR09 = c(2,3,4,4,4,2)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
 
  
  return(df1)
}

f1 <- function(df1, dmda, CategoryChosse) {
  
  x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DR0"))
  
  x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
  PV<-select(x, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))
  
  med<-PV %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median))
  
  SPV<-df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Category', 'Week')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())
  
  SPV<-data.frame(SPV)
  
  mat1 <- df1 %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(starts_with("DR0")) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
    mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
    filter(cs == 0) %>%
    pull(name)
  
  (dropnames <- paste0(mat1,"_",mat1, "_PV"))
  
  SPV <- SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(-any_of(dropnames))
  
  datas<-SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
    group_by(Category) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR0"), sum)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols= -Category, names_pattern = "DR0(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = readr::parse_number(name))
  colnames(datas)[-1]<-c("Days","Numbers")
  
  if(as.Date(dmda) < min(as.Date(df1$date1))){
    datas <- datas %>% 
      group_by(Category) %>% 
      slice(1:max(Days)+1) %>%
      ungroup
  }else{
    datas <- datas %>% 
      group_by(Category) %>% 
      slice((as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
        df1$Category == first(Category)])):max(Days)+1) %>%
      ungroup
  }
  
  plot(Numbers ~ Days,  xlim= c(0,45), ylim= c(0,30),
       xaxs='i',data = datas,main = paste0(dmda, "-", CategoryChosse))
  
  model <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = datas, algorithm = "port")
  
  new.data <- data.frame(Days = with(datas, seq(min(Days),max(Days),len = 45)))
  new.data <- rbind(0, new.data)
  lines(new.data$Days,predict(model,newdata = new.data),lwd=2)
  coef<-coef(model)[2]
  points(0, coef, col="red",pch=19,cex = 2,xpd=TRUE)
  text(.99,coef + 1,max(0, round(coef,1)), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")
  
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       
                                       uiOutput("date"),
                                       uiOutput("mycode"),
                                       br(),
                                       
                                       
                                     ),
                                     
                                     mainPanel(
                                       tabsetPanel(
                                         tabPanel("", plotOutput("graph",width = "100%", height = "600")
                                         )
                                       ),
                                     ))
                          )))


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(function.test())
  
  output$date <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    subdf1 <- subset(data(), as.Date(date2) > as.Date(date1))
    all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
    disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date2)), origin = "1970-01-01")
    dateInput(input = "date2", 
              label = h4("Data"),
              min = min(subdf1$date2),
              max = max(subdf1$date2),
              value = min(subdf1$date2),
              format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
              datesdisabled = disabled)
    
  })
  
  output$mycode <- renderUI({
    req(input$date2)
    df1 <- data()
    df2 <- df1[as.Date(df1$date2) %in% input$date2,]
    selectInput("code", label = h4("Code"),choices=unique(df2$Category))
  })
  
  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    req(input$date2,input$code)
    f1(data(),as.character(input$date2),as.character(input$code))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks akrun for the reply. Is this the only way to do it? I say this because in this brief example it worked, but when I went to make it to a much larger base, I gave this error: ` negative length vectors are not allowed` when I make this change that you inserted up there. If I leave it unchanged, the graphics are generated normally. I found it strange, if you want I can insert the figure above.

Comment: @JVieira I think it could be because when `subset` is not returning any rows i.e. when none of the date values are greater than date1 perhaps.  So, I am guessing that your condition of subsetting would be an issue

Comment: Is there no way to make this `return (subdf1)` at another time?

Comment: @JVieira What I meant to say is that there are many places where the `data()` is being used.  If you require the full 'df1' in other places and only the subset in date, then this needs to be changed only in dateInput case. i..e `f1(data(),as.character(input$date2),as.character(input$code))` the f1 takes the output of reactive function as well

Comment: @JVieira can you try the update

Comment: Sure, thanks akrun, I will check

Comment: Very good Akrun, it works! You are ninja in R!

Comment: Just to know, do you changed just  `output$date`?

Comment: @JVieira Yes, `subdf1 <- subset(data(), as.Date(date2) > as.Date(date1))` and also in the `min/max` instead of `data()`, i used `subdf1`

Comment: Hi @akrun, please, can you see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70620140/how-to-set-options-received-in-selectinput-into-shiny-code