# How to set options received in selectInput into shiny code

Tags: r, shiny

I'm having a problem when I select options in my `selectInput`. Note that if I select 30/06, two ids will appear, which are 1 and 5. If I choose 5, I would have to show only 1 code, as I have only one observation for id =5, however, as you can see by the image below, it is appearing twice. So I need to adjust this questions on my `server`.

Executable code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

  df1 <- structure(
    list(id=c("1","5","1","1"),
         date1= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
         date2 = c("2021-06-30","2021-06-30","2021-07-01","2021-07-01"),
         Category = c("FDE","ABC","FDE","ABC"),
         Week= c("Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Friday"),
         DR1 = c(4,7,6,3),
         DR01 = c(4,1,4,3), DR02= c(4,9,6,2),DR03= c(9,5,4,7),
         DR04 = c(5,6,3,2),DR05 = c(5,4,5,4),
         DR06 = c(2,6,3,2),DR07 = c(2,2,4,4),
         DR08 = c(3,6,5,4),DR09 = c(2,3,4,4)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

f1 <- function(df1, dmda, CategoryChosse) {
  
  x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DR0"))
  
  x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
  PV<-select(x, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))
  
  med<-PV %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median))
  
  SPV<-df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Category', 'Week')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())
  
  SPV<-data.frame(SPV)
  
  mat1 <- df1 %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(starts_with("DR0")) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
    mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
    filter(cs == 0) %>%
    pull(name)
  
  (dropnames <- paste0(mat1,"_",mat1, "_PV"))
  
  SPV <- SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(-any_of(dropnames))
  
  datas<-SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
    group_by(Category) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR0"), sum)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols= -Category, names_pattern = "DR0(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = readr::parse_number(name))
  colnames(datas)[-1]<-c("Days","Numbers")
  
  datas <- datas %>% 
    group_by(Category) %>% 
    slice((as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
      df1$Category == first(Category)])):max(Days)+1) %>%
    ungroup
  
  plot(Numbers ~ Days,  xlim= c(0,45), ylim= c(0,30),
       xaxs='i',data = datas,main = paste0(dmda, "-", CategoryChosse))
  
  model <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = datas, algorithm = "port")
  
  new.data <- data.frame(Days = with(datas, seq(min(Days),max(Days),len = 45)))
  new.data <- rbind(0, new.data)
  coef<-coef(model)[2]
  points(0, coef, col="red",pch=19,cex = 2,xpd=TRUE)
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       
                                       uiOutput("date"),
                                       uiOutput("id"),
                                       uiOutput("mycode"),
                                       br(),
                                       
                                       
                                     ),
                                     
                                     mainPanel(
                                       tabsetPanel(
                                         tabPanel("", plotOutput("graph",width = "100%", height = "600")
                                         )
                                       ),
                                     ))
                          )))


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(df1)
  
  output$date <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
    disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date2)), origin = "1970-01-01")
    dateInput(input = "date2", 
              label = h4("Data"),
              min = min(data()$date2),
              max = max(data()$date2),
              format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
              datesdisabled = disabled)
    
  })
  
  output$id <- renderUI({
    req(input$date2)
    df1 <- data()
    df2 <- df1[as.Date(df1$date2) %in% input$date2,]
    selectInput("idd", label = h4("Id"),choices=unique(df2$id))
  })
  
  
  output$mycode <- renderUI({
    req(input$date2,input$idd)
    df1 <- data()
    df2 <- df1[as.Date(df1$date2) %in% input$date2,]
    selectInput("code", label = h4("Code"),choices=unique(df2$Category))
  })
  
 
  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    req(input$date2,input$idd,input$code)
    f1(data(),as.character(input$date2),as.character(input$code))
  })

  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly convoluted, but I think a couple of minor adjustments might be helpful here. First, you might want to double check what inputs you include in `req`. Second, you may want to filter your data based on `input$idd` when you provide `code` options. Let me know if this is helpful.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- reactive(df1)
  
  output$date <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
    disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date2)), origin = "1970-01-01")
    dateInput(input = "date2", 
              label = h4("Data"),
              min = min(data()$date2),
              max = max(data()$date2),
              format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
              datesdisabled = disabled)
  })
  
  output$id <- renderUI({
    req(input$date2)
    df1 <- data()
    df2 <- df1[as.Date(df1$date2) %in% input$date2,]
    selectInput("idd", label = h4("Id"),choices=unique(df2$id))
  })
  
  output$mycode <- renderUI({
    req(input$date2, input$idd)
    df1 <- data()
    df2 <- df1[as.Date(df1$date2) %in% input$date2 & input$idd == df1$id, ]
    selectInput("code", label = h4("Code"),choices=unique(df2$Category))
  })
  
  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    req(input$date2, input$idd, input$code)
    f1(data(),as.character(input$date2),as.character(input$code))
  })
  
}
```

Comment: That's it @Ben, I just had one question: In `f1(data(),as.character(input$date2),as.character(input$code))`, don't you need to insert `input$idd` too?

Comment: I didn't change that line of code or look at `f1`. Maybe you could check over `f1` function and see. If you do need to use it you can pass it to your function. But again, it's fairly complicated to sift through.